# Rails, Devise: invalid login redirects to root page instead of displaying errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, authentication, devise

For some reason, my app redirects failed session creation to the root page of the application, instead of displaying errors on why the login failed, such as, wrong password.

I captured the http response:

```
Request URL:http://localhost:3000/users/sign_in
Request Method:POST
Status Code:302 Moved Temporarily
```

My code performs a :

```
<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => session_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
```

If I change the url to user_session_path - I get the following:

```
Invalid email or password.
```

However, it is just rendered as simple text.

```
Request URL:http://localhost:3000/users/sign_in.user
Request Method:POST
Status Code:401 Unauthorized
```

I have omniauth and cancan gems installed. Not sure where to start looking - any ideas?
(on another note, I do not see the route session in rake routes, but if I perform a correct login, it logs me in. How is this possible?)

Thank you!

Comment: I suppose you already have devise_for :users in config/routes.rb?

Comment: Do you have any before filters in your controllers that check login status?

Answer (score 0):

I found that my app had a CustomFailure class in the lib folder. This always redirect to the root upon login. After removing this failure app, the app redirected me back to the login screen after a failed login.

According to [Rails - Devise - Error messages when signing in?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4635986/rails-devise-error-messages-when-signing-in) , the errors are not given to form fields, but to flash messages. So you need to include them to the default devise new session view.

I still did not figure out why session_path works, and why user_session_path produces the results posted in my question.