# Login through devise is not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, devise

I am using rails app with angular js for authentication purpose i am using devise gem. When i am submitting sign in form, i am unable to login it is redirecting to same page.

*app/views/devise/sessions/new.html.erb* :

```
       <form class="form-horizontal">
                <%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: session_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
                <fieldset>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
                          <span class="input-group-addon">
                              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span>
                          </span>
                                <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true , class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'Email'%>
                        </div>
                    </div>  

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
                            <span class="input-group-addon">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></span>
                            </span>
                            <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off" , class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'Password'%>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">

                        <%= button_tag(type: 'submit', class: "btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block") do %>
                             Login
                        <% end %>
                   </div>

                </fieldset>
                <% end %>
            </form>
```

Could any one explain where i am making mistake?

Comment: are you updating any of devises methods? if you are then can you post them

Comment: I didn't update devise methods.

Comment: can you post your logs then? It'll give you an idea of what exactly is happening behind the scenes when you click on sign in button

Comment: Started GET "/users/sign_in?utf8=%E2%9C%93&authenticity_token=27TrFYYcMELJ%2F%2Ff1cub1brDww%2B6RDmRtnOgno6q6J0w%3D&user%5Bemail%5D=user1%40gmail.com&user%5Bpassword%5D=[FILTERED]" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-06-11 14:47:17 +0530
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#new as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"27TrFYYcMELJ//f1cub1brDww+6RDmRtnOgno6q6J0w=", "user"=>{"email"=>"user1@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}}
  Rendered layouts/_navbar.html.erb (0.0ms)
  Rendered devise/sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application (1.2ms)

Comment: In console i am getting like this @user2675613

Comment: if you look at your logs devise has redirected back to `Rendered devise/sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application`. If your password were wrong devise would have notified you but still are you sure your password is correct?

Comment: @AnushaNilapu try: restart server

Comment: @nithin that i did so many times

Comment: @AnushaNilapu https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#getting-started hope you have followed this

Comment: `<%=devise_error_messages! %>` in your view after `form_for` does it say anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The problem is here we are using form_for and form both. I forget to update the answer. Using one thing fixes my problem. Thank you for trying to help me.*

Answer (score 1):

U must have missed out on adding..

```
before_filter :authenticate_user!
```

in your controller

Comment: this method kicks in when you are not signed in and in this case she **did sign in**

Comment: So how can i avoid redirecting to sign in page even though signed in @user2675613

Comment: @AnushaNilapu `root_path` is set? and u have any ajax call in login page

Comment: I didn't used any ajax call @nithin

Answer (score 0):

**Errors**

The problem you have will be you've got errors with your form, and as devise uses `<%= devise_error_messages! %>` with login forms (and doesn't work out of the box).

You'll likely be receiving errors from your login attempts, but because you can't see them in your view, it *seems* like you're just being redirected back to the login page.

--

**Test**

A good way to test this will be to put this in your `sessions/new.html.erb` file:

```
<% if user_signed_in? %>
 SIGNED IN
<% else %>
 NOT SIGNED IN
<% end %>
```

This will show you if the `session` has been created for the user or not (I.E they've been logged in). If not, I would suggest you've got errors which you're unable to see

--

**Fix**

If the problem is you're receiving errors, the way to fix them will be to use one of the ways to show them in your view. We have used [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4635986/rails-devise-error-messages-when-signing-in) before to create this:

```
#app/views/devise/sessions/new.html.haml
= form_for resource, as: resource_name, url: session_path(resource_name), remote: request.xhr? do |f|
    = devise_error_messages!

#app/helpers/devise_helper.rb
Module DeviseHelper

  def devise_error_messages!
    flash_alerts = []
    error_key = 'errors.messages.not_saved'

    if !flash.empty?
      flash_alerts.push(flash[:error]) if flash[:error]
      flash_alerts.push(flash[:alert]) if flash[:alert]
      flash_alerts.push(flash[:notice]) if flash[:notice]
      error_key = 'devise.failure.invalid'
    end

    return "" if resource.errors.empty? && flash_alerts.empty?
    errors = resource.errors.empty? ? flash_alerts : resource.errors.full_messages

    messages = errors.map { |msg| content_tag(:li, msg) }.join
    sentence = I18n.t(error_key, :count    => errors.count,
                                 :resource => resource.class.model_name.human.downcase)

    html = <<-HTML
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2>#{sentence}</h2>
      <ul>#{messages}</ul>
    </div>
    HTML

    html.html_safe
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you for your information. But how can i solve this problem. I am unable to sign in and sign up

Comment: Have you migrated the devise migration to your db? Have you got the devise initializer on your system?

Comment: Yes. I did migration and i also had devise initializer

Comment: And you can't register? Why not? Does nothing happen? What's the deal?

Comment: I can able to login when i used complete ruby code after i customized the view from that point i am unable to login or sign up